# Recovering class files that were deleted when cleaning eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, recovery

I recently ran out of disc space so I cleaned eclipse while under the impression that it doesn't actually delete any class files. When I restarted eclipse I noticed many of my files were missing, but strangely, some weren't. I then chose to restore files from "restore from local history" option but not all came back, and some that came back weren't complete.

Does anyone know how I'd fix this? I'm very worried as there are months worth of important work here. How can I recover these files?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about `.class` files (which are generated automatically by building) or `.java` files? Local history only keeps source files like .java, not .class files. Discs can fail, **always** keep backups of important files. Also use a source control system like Git or SVN which provides another source of backups.

Comment: Eclipse installation folder does not (or should not) contain source code. And you should **always** always have a source control system as @greg-449 said already.

Comment: .class files should be recreated when you build the project.